# spring security 2.0.6 AuthenticationProcessingFilter authenticationFailureUrl not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, spring-security

I solved my issue here.

I had forgotten about the following:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
    <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
```

As you can see from above I do have /index.jsp and that is where it is trying to go.

The other issue is the following line

```
  <concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
```

So this tells me to throw and exception.

So in the end - everything appears to be working as expected.

---

Original Post:

As the subject states I have the following configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/admin/adminLanding.html"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
    <beans:property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="targetUrlResolver" ref="roleBasedTargetUrlResolver" />
</beans:bean>
```

My expectation is that when a authentication fails or has expired that it would make use of the setting for authenticationFailureURL.  But what I get is the following error in my log:

The requested resource (/ecotrak/index.jsp) is not available.

I do not understand why it is looking for index.jsp when I have given /login.jsp?login_error=1 as the value.

Any direction it this?

Comment: What is the URL that you are accessing for which you see the mentioned error in the log?  Is it /ecotrack/index.jsp?

Comment: @Raghuram - When I wait for the site to time out - 30 minutes or so and I go to select and page, my expectation is that that login page would be displayed.  But, it appears to want to go to the index.jsp page - which I do not have.  So how can I get it to go to the login page when a user session has timed out?